# How to get row from R data.frame

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I have a data.frame with column headers.

How can I get a specific row from the data.frame as a list (with the column headers as keys for the list)?

Specifically, my data.frame is

```
      A    B    C
    1 5    4.25 4.5
    2 3.5  4    2.5
    3 3.25 4    4
    4 4.25 4.5  2.25
    5 1.5  4.5  3
```

And I want to get a row that's the equivalent of

```
> c(a=5, b=4.25, c=4.5)
  a   b   c 
5.0 4.25 4.5
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
x[r,]
```

where r is the row you're interested in.  Try this, for example:

```
#Add your data
x <- structure(list(A = c(5,    3.5, 3.25, 4.25,  1.5 ), 
                    B = c(4.25, 4,   4,    4.5,   4.5 ),
                    C = c(4.5,  2.5, 4,    2.25,  3   )
               ),
               .Names    = c("A", "B", "C"),
               class     = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -5L)
     )

#The vector your result should match
y<-c(A=5, B=4.25, C=4.5)

#Test that the items in the row match the vector you wanted
x[1,]==y
```

[This page](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/html/b6.html) (from [this useful site](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/index.html)) has good information on indexing like this.

Answer (score 16):

Logical indexing is very R-ish.  Try:

```
 x[ x$A ==5 & x$B==4.25 & x$C==4.5 , ]
```

Or:

```
subset( x, A ==5 & B==4.25 & C==4.5 )
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
> d <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6, c=7:9)

> d
  a b c
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9

> d[1, ]
  a b c
1 1 4 7

> d[1, ]['a']
  a
1 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the row number, but do know some values then you can use subset

```
x <- structure(list(A = c(5,    3.5, 3.25, 4.25,  1.5 ), 
                    B = c(4.25, 4,   4,    4.5,   4.5 ),
                    C = c(4.5,  2.5, 4,    2.25,  3   )
               ),
               .Names    = c("A", "B", "C"),
               class     = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -5L)
     )

subset(x, A ==5 & B==4.25 & C==4.5)
```

Comment: do you mean this instead?

    subset(x, A==5 && B==4.25 && C==4.5)

Comment: No, it should have been: `subset(x, A ==5 & B==4.25 & C==4.5)`

Answer (score 3):

10 years later ---> Using tidyverse we could achieve this simply and borrowing a leaf from [Christopher Bottoms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269719/13119339). For a better grasp, see [`slice()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html).

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- structure(list(A = c(5,    3.5, 3.25, 4.25,  1.5 ), 
                    B = c(4.25, 4,   4,    4.5,   4.5 ),
                    C = c(4.5,  2.5, 4,    2.25,  3   )
),
.Names    = c("A", "B", "C"),
class     = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)

x
#>      A    B    C
#> 1 5.00 4.25 4.50
#> 2 3.50 4.00 2.50
#> 3 3.25 4.00 4.00
#> 4 4.25 4.50 2.25
#> 5 1.50 4.50 3.00

y<-c(A=5, B=4.25, C=4.5)
y
#>    A    B    C 
#> 5.00 4.25 4.50

#The slice() verb allows one to subset data row-wise. 
x <- x %>% slice(1) #(n) for the nth row, or (i:n) for range i to n, (i:n()) for i to last row...

x
#>   A    B   C
#> 1 5 4.25 4.5

#Test that the items in the row match the vector you wanted
x[1,]==y
#>      A    B    C
#> 1 TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>